# Is it possible to send an iOS app to a client to test without an Apple Developer ID and iPhone device?

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, device

I'm working on an iOS app. Just now I've completed my app. I'm testing it in simulator. Now I want to send this app to a client to test.

I do not have an Apple developer account (paid) and neither does my client. Also I do not have an iPhone device. Is it possible to give my app to client without these? If yes, what is the process?

Comment: How can you even know that this application works without testing it on the device? It doesn't show much respect for your client or their potential users to not even test this before shipping it to them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strictly not! you need an *Apple developer account* for the development testing and uploading your app to **App store** as well.

From [here](https://developer.apple.com/support/compare-memberships/), you can choose the membership. And here is an [App Distribution Quick Start](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppStoreDistributionTutorial/Setup/Setup.html).

You have to register your devices in your developer account. That's how it works!. It associates with all the device UDIDs with your developer account.

Comment: Do i need developer's account to run app in iPhone device?

Comment: yes, for sure you need dev account because you have to add your device in your dev certificate and then install in your system. then choosing that certificate will make your app work in that added device.

Comment: Excuse me bro, I have one apple id which is created without paying money. Will I be able to do anything with that ID?

Comment: No, you cannot do anything with that id bro. you have to pay for publishing or testing on real-time devices.

Comment: @AnuragSharma That's no longer true. You can deploy to devices you personally own with a free developer account. A paid account is required for distribution through TestFlight or the App Store. If you want to send a Simulator-only build to someone, locate the .app bundle in the build products directory, compress it, and send it. The person can uncompress it then drag the .app onto the Simulator window to install it.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible. You need an Apple developer account for certificates and profiles. Without these you can't test app on device.